# How to add a two-dimensional array directly to a hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, int

Instead of this:

```
int[][] someArr = { { 88, 35 }, { 11, 98 } };
mapDE = new HashMap<String, int[][]>();
mapDE.put("someKey", someArr);
```

I would like to do this in order to save a code of line:

```
mapDE = new HashMap<String, int[][]>();
mapDE.put("someKey", { { 88, 35 }, { 11, 98 } });
```

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapDE.put("someKey", { { 88, 35 }, { 11, 98 } });` does not compile because `{ { 88, 35 }, { 11, 98 } }` wont ensure the type `int[][]`

You could try by this way:

```
    Map<String, int[][]> mapDE = new HashMap<String, int[][]>();
    mapDE.put("someKey",new int[][] { { 88, 35 }, { 11, 98 } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
mapDE.put("somekey", new int[][]{
  { 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0 } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, try the following:

```
mapDE.put("someKey", new int[][]{{88, 35}, {11, 98}});
```